# How to automatically update database SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I need a field (column) of my database to update automatically. For example, the field NUMBER for each record incrementing every minute. How can I do it? I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for something called SQL Server Agent jobs

here is a good starting point reference:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx

This allows you to run some sql code on a schedule of your choosing.

P.S.

If you have access to sql server management studio, the GUI is much nicer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a SQL Agent job to run an update statement once a minute:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET NUMBER = NUMBER + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Job Agent is only for full SQL Server. Then best choise. If you using SQL express then can't. You can solve with update

```
UPDATE TABLE-NAME SET
VALUE = VALUE + 1
```